# Import an image to jsp file using <c:import url=""/>

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

How can I automatically get the file path of an image using `<c:import url=""/>` as src of `<img src="" alt""/>`
To be more specific, below is the requiment:

Create a card with the following structure
`<c:ImportUrl url = “…”/>`
here url property will work like this:
`url = “/img/avatar.png”` the url attribute can point to the address of
any resource.
if current context (current path is /list)
then automatically `c:ImportUrl` will return the text containing the command to convert from
current context to the resource pointed to by the url.

Eg:
We have the context: build the page /list according to the MVC pattern
when every request goes through Controller, instead of direct request
to the view (usually written in jsp).
Whether the jsp file address is : `/view/test/list.jsp`
The address of an image file to include in the view is: `/img/avatar.png`
To show this image file
`<img src = “<c:ImportUrl url="/img/avatar.png”/>”`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value of the generated url into a variable and then use that variable:

```html
<c:import var="image" url="/img/avatar.png"/>
<img src = "${image}" alt="..." />
```

Comment: I tried this before but it's just display a page full of characters like this "üÀ§­ëZKkÚç1}Jm=¥BÀ$%Î®ï$î»eü¿ÔG@G5¥.9wÊ Ù÷kµ%Ô]?Ô5ýß@®ÛZùïtz=~& iµ]ÓMxì! ·nðañø[2|¨s!ôÓTtÏÇðPH§$ ¥°½@Jaz D\7z¼·>QúÁ*]Ü<´W,"

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and Base 64 encoding works, but you might have to force a specific character encoding/content-type character set.

Here is a JSP excerpt that uses JSP scriptlet to do the Base64 encoding:

```
<c:import url="https://my.server.com/get-png-data" var="imageData"/>
<% String base64data = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( ((String) pageContext.getAttribute("imageData")).getBytes()); %>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%=base64Data%>"/>
```

On a couple of systems, I had to explicitly use `...getBytes("ISO-8859-1")`.

I'd also recommend, by the way, wrapping that `<c:import>` in a `<c:catch>` in case there are failures. Like this:

```
<c:catch var="importException">
    <c:import url="https://my.server.com/get-png-data" var="imageData"/>
    ...
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${not empty importException}">
    <c:out value="${importException}"/> <%-- do something else here to handle --%>
</c:if>
```